# Require Rows which lies between two dates

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I got table having dates columns as `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` 
It has data which is valid for that range of days .
If I have current date as my date to send which checks for dates between ValidFrom and ValidTo .
How can I get rows of data which satisfies the condition for two columns of dates instead of having to look into each row.

Comment: Have you tried SELECT .. WHERE ?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE '2017-03-01' >= '2017-01-11' (ValidFrom value )
AND '2017-03-01' <= '2017-04-28' (ValidTo value ) , but this would give for only one row at a time , will require to add for loop for going through each record. I need a single query to check out the whole row list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make rawQuery

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ValidFrom < %yourDate% AND ValidTO < %yourDate%;", null);

cursor.moveToFirst();
while ( !cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        //get here values you need from raw
            cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: How can I have it for multiple rows , the single query. Should I use for loop ?

Comment: @Yatin you will have **all** rows for this expression

Comment: @DEADMC you need to switch the < > around you have valid from greater than date and valid to less than date

Comment: sorry ! @DEADMC !!  i've not noticed this answer